# swift segue new viewcontroller stuck when other tasks loading on background

Tags: ios, swift, uitableview, segue

Currently, I have a UItableview which loads based on API. And when clicking on a cell, it segue(show e.g.push) to another viewcontroller. It displays all the cells after the first API call, then it calls other APIs and loads other data(which takes a while and also uses cpu heavily), but the scrolling seems to be smooth when loading.
However, when not fully loaded, if I click on a cell and the other viewController pops up, the entire app freezes for a moment. (The new viewController has all the content displayed, just not responsive)
Is there a solution for this?
What I can think of right now is to decrease the CPU load by loading fewer cells at a time.

Comment: Welcome to SO. Please read [ask] and provide some code (a [example]) to share what you are doing.

Comment: You might not be using the main thread correctly. Your intensive calls that are loading data should be done on a background thread and only update the UI on the main thread.

Answer (score 0):

Typically you are not going to want to do this:

> "loads other data(which takes a while and also uses cpu heavily)"

The better solution would be to not call your second call to fetch all the data and just fetch the data needed to show on your next view controller you are segueing to. Typically done by passing an ID in your API call. So on your tableviews `didSelectRowAt` you would make the api call to get your data needed that is specific to the next screen, then segue.

If this is not possible due to server side limitations, then you are going to want to chain your first two calls. Meaning don't even show the table view cells until you have all the data.